# Create new or add to standard composite enhancement point: pros and cons?

Tags: abap

I want to implement an enhancement point in the include: `LMRMPF1R`

It seems that there is already one existing enhancement `/NFM/MM_SAPLMRMP`:

[image: Click here for image]

After clicking on "create enhancement implementation" following screen is shown, where I can see the `/NFM/MM_SAPLMRMP` again, which is part of the composite enhancement implementation `/SAPMP/EC`.

[image: Click here for image]

When I create a new one I can choose if I want to add the implementation to an existing composite enhancement implementation. As it is in the same place, it is recommended to add it to the same composite enhancement implementation?

[image: Click here for image]

If I do so, I am mentioned as the user who changed the "standard" composite enhancement implementation `/SAPMP/EC`. Originally SAP is mentioned there. After I add it, I am.

This [SAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw75/7.5.5/en-US/5f/103a4280da9923e10000000a155106/frameset.htm) just says "Select a composite enhancement implementation, or create a new one" but does not tell me the pros and cons.

While browsing the web, I read a lot of "HowTos" and everyone just leaves the field empty, so they do not add it to a  composite enhancement implementation

As I want to code along BestPractices, your input is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The implementation you have here is in the partner namespace `/SAPMP/`. Unless you happen to be working for the organization which manages that namespace, you might run into various problems when trying to use it. For example when you install an update which changes that implementation.

So it's usually a better idea to create an own enhancement implementation in the `Z` namespace.

Regarding the question of composite vs, stand-alone enhancements: I would recommend composite enhancement when you are implementing a larger feature which consists of many smaller features which are each implemented through an own enhancement. A composite enhancement allows you to logically group those enhancements together. That way a developer who looks at your implementation later will recognize that there is more than one enhancement which plays a role for this feature. It is also possible to enable and disable this feature by enabling and disabling your composite enhancement. With multiple regular enhancements, another developer or consultant can't be that sure that they really toggled all the enhancements they needed.

But when the feature you are implementing only requires a single enhancement, then there is usually no reason to assign it to a composite enhancement.

Also, just because two enhancement insert code at the same place does not necessarily mean that they are about the same feature. So that alone is no reason to logically group them into one composite enhancement.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately, SAP allowed me (somehow) without asking for a Key, to add my Z enhancement to the composite enhancement. I already removed it. So it is in the original version again.

The only difference now is, that the information about the "last change" is now set to my username. Even if I try to revert to the original Version, "last change" is set to my username again.

Is there any way to resolve this, or can this cause problems while updating the system? In the Version-Management, the flag which says "SAP Standard" is set correctly.

Comment: @misterxyz That's a completely new question unrelated to this one. Please ask it as a new question.

Comment: Can you just tell me if it is possible, yes or no, then I will create a new one if the answer is yes

Comment: @misterxyz There is always a way (but not always a way worth taking). Please ask it as a new question.